# Trying to avoid sql injection attack - leads to data not being inserted

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to avoid an SQL injection attack and thanks to @Matthew Johnson, I'm nearly there ( I think ).

When I submit the form, the data is not added to my table.  Is there something I am missing in this code?

**Why isn't the data inserting into my table?**

```
 <?php

 if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

 include ('cc_connect.php');

 if (!$dbcon) {
die("Can not Connect: " . mysql_error());

}

mysql_select_db("cooperstown",$dbcon);

$first_name = isset($_POST['first_name']) ? $_POST['first_name'] : '';
$last_name = isset($_POST['last_name']) ? $_POST['last_name'] : '';
$street = isset($_POST['street']) ? $_POST['street'] : '';
$city = isset($_POST['city']) ? $_POST['city'] : '';
$state = isset($_POST['state']) ? $_POST['state'] : '';
$zip = isset($_POST['zip']) ? $_POST['zip'] : '';
$home_phone = isset($_POST['home_phone']) ? $_POST['home_phone'] : '';
$email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : '';
$birth_month = isset($_POST['birth_month']) ? $_POST['birth_month'] : '';
$birth_day = isset($_POST['birth_day']) ? $_POST['birth_day'] : '';
$birth_year = isset($_POST['birth_year']) ? $_POST['birth_year'] : '';
$grade = isset($_POST['grade']) ? $_POST['grade'] : '';
$school = isset($_POST['school']) ? $_POST['school'] : '';
$tryout_date = isset($_POST['tryout_date']) ? $_POST['tryout_date'] : '';
$guard1_first_name = isset($_POST['guard1_first_name']) ? $_POST['guard1_first_name'] : '';
$guard1_last_name = isset($_POST['guard1_last_name']) ? $_POST['guard1_last_name'] : '';
$guard1_email = isset($_POST['guard1_email']) ? $_POST['guard1_email'] : '';
$guard1_phone = isset($_POST['guard1_phone']) ? $_POST['guard1_phone'] : '';
$guard1_cell = isset($_POST['guard1_cell']) ? $_POST['guard1_cell'] : '';
$guard2_first_name = isset($_POST['guard2_first_name']) ? $_POST['guard2_first_name'] : '';
$guard2_last_name = isset($_POST['guard2_last_name']) ? $_POST['guard2_last_name'] : '';
$guard2_email = isset($_POST['guard2_email']) ? $_POST['guard2_email'] : '';
$guard2_phone = isset($_POST['guard2_phone']) ? $_POST['guard2_phone'] : '';
$guard2_cell = isset($_POST['guard2_cell']) ? $_POST['guard2_cell'] : '';


if ($first_name && $last_name && $street && $city && $state && $zip && $home_phone && $email && $birth_month && $birth_day && $birth_year && $grade && $school && $tryout_date && $guard1_first_name && $guard1_last_name && $guard1_email && $guard1_phone && $guard1_cell && $guard2_first_name && $guard2_last_name && $guard2_email && $guard2_phone && $guard2_cell) {

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO cobra_registration (first_name,last_name,street,city,state,zip,home_phone,email,birth_month,birth_day,birth_year,grade,school,tryout_date,guard1_first_name,guard1_last_name,guard1_email,guard1_phone,guard1_cell,guard2_first_name,guard2_last_name,guard2_email,guard2_phone,guard2_cell) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("sssssiisiiiisssssiisssii", $first_name, $last_name, $street, $city, $state, $zip, $home_phone, $email, $birth_month, $birth_day, $birth_year, $grade, $school, $tryout_date, $guard1_first_name, $guard1_last_name, $guard1_email, $guard1_phone, $guard1_cell, $guard2_first_name, $guard2_last_name, $guard2_email, $guard2_phone, $guard2_cell)
$stmt->execute();
}


}

?>
```

Comment: Are you getting the SQL provided from $stmt ? I recommend to you use a generic method to convert a lots of params into a stdClass ....

Comment: You have a variable named $mysqli yet you are using mysql (no i) features. Are you using mysqli in your connection file?

Comment: Can't you let `bind_param` do the conversion for you instead of having to test every single input parameter with `isset`? Additionally, if you're doing this much validation, what you really need is a 
[development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) to bring some order to this chaos.

Comment: @tadman The purpose of `isset()` is to avoid notices about undefined indexes, it has nothing to do with binding parameters.

Comment: really sorry for the lack of knowledge here.  I am new to php... my connect file is "mysql-connect".... I tried changing "$mysqli..." to "$mysql..." with no luck.  I was sure it wasn't that simple but as I mentioned... new to php.

Comment: Please show how you're assigning `$dbcon` in the include file. It looks like you may be using `mysql_connect()`, not `mysqli_connect()`. You can't mix `mysql` and `mysqli`, they're totally unrelated.

Comment: Are there suggestions to avoid injection better than this method I found via this forum?  My initial form setup was simple compared to this but I was advised is was "WIDE open to SQL Injection Attacks"... I'm not sure which direction to go.

Comment: What you're missing is that the recommendations generally involve writing the code correctly in the first place. There are no quick fixes to existing code.

Comment: Here are details on my connection file:

$dbcon = new mysqli("server","user","pw","database");
if (!$dbcon) {
      die ("Cannot connect: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

Comment: @jd5 That is a problem. See Barmer's comment above. You can not mix mysql and mysqli together.

Comment: so dumb question... do I simply replace "mysql" with "mysqli"?

Answer (score 4):

In order to use mysqli prepared statements, you have to connect to the database using mysqli:

```
$dbcon = new mysqli("server", "username", "password", "database");
if (!$dbcon) {
    die ("Cannot connect: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

Comment: I would also take a look at your database design. I'm noticing `guard1` and `guard2`, that's not a good sign.

Comment: "guard1" and "guard2" are simply column headers short for "guardian 1" and "guardian 2"... not sure how that is not a good sign.

Comment: When you have repeated columns like that, it suggests that your schema may not be normalized properly. E.g. what if someone has more than 2 guardians?

Comment: more than 2?  I'm only request the first 2 guardians info.  not sure I follow your logic?  please explain...

Comment: The point is that your schema should be designed to be general. You shouldn't have a built-in limit on the number of repetitions of something. If you have columns like `guardian1`, `guardian2`, .... Then you're limited to the number of columns you have. If you move them into a separate table, where each guardian is in a row of its own, there's no imposed limit.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote an application previously, which, albeit simpler, and open to attack, worked. You were then told that your database related code was using bad practice's, and you have attempted a slightly more 'advanced' practice. After looking at your code, and your database design, I suggest that you are trying to run before you can walk. All developers, particularly those whose first language is PHP, come the route you are taking, and much is learnt, and problems are found, which leads us on to solutions such as PDO and prepared statements. But we get there by doing our 'time', learning in its most simple form, and only then do we get an understanding and appreciation of SQL injection.

The real issue here is your lack of programming knowledge, which comes with time; playing, breaking things, on play projects that couldn't care less about SQL injection. This is why I suggest you learn to walk before you can run. First work on your programming.

The worst outcome for you here is someone finding the line of code that is causing your problem, and you will continue on your way, without addressing the real problems in your code; an unthinkably long `if` statement and lack of database design knowledge spring to mind.

If Barmar's solution solves your problem, your real problem was not knowing that you were using an object variable that you were yet to instantiate.

If I was to set you on your way, I would recommend reading [Head First PHP and MySQL](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Head-First-MySQL-Lynn-Beighley/dp/0596006306)